# Transposing a list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, dictionary

Having some trouble trying to come up with the most pythonic way to rearrange this list of dictionaries...

```
[{1: ['s1e1.csv', 's1e2.csv']}, 
 {2: ['s2e1.csv', 's2e2.csv']}]
```

So that it is arranged like this...

```
[{1: 's1e1.csv', 2: 's2e1.csv'},
 {1: 's1e2.csv', 2: 's2e2.csv'}]
```

My first thought was to transpose, but it isn't quite working how I'd expect it to with lists. Perhaps just transposing the *values* of the two dicts without the keys might be a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```py
vals = [{1: ['s1e1.csv', 's1e2.csv']}, {2: ['s2e1.csv', 's2e2.csv']}]

newvals = [{1: vals [0][1][x], 2: vals [1][2][x]} for x in range(2)]

# Output: [{1: 's1e1.csv', 2: 's2e1.csv'}, {1: 's1e2.csv', 2: 's2e2.csv'}]
```